# Каковы основные различия между языками описания оборудования и языком сборки (языком ассемблера)?

Tags: ассемблер, железо

Каковы основные различия между языками описания оборудования и языком сборки?

Comment: [What's the motivation in using Verilog or VHDL over C?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/132611)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основным отличием является то, что

VHDL/HDL описывает **аппаратные** компоненты. Это, в основном, способ описания большой электронной схемы. Он «компилируется» в *трафарет чипа*, который в дальнейшем может быть использован для производства чипа.

Язык ассемблера – это низкоуровневый язык, который понимает CPU, так как каждая его инструкция соответствует инструкции машинного кода.

<sub>перевод https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-hardware-description-language-hdl-and-assembly-language</sub>